# Org mode HTML export presets

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, template

When I export something with org mode to html, with it comes a load of presets such as id, labels, classes, preambles and post ambles.

For example:

`<div id="outline-container-org16cf335" class="outline-2">`

I would like to remove all of this or to at least be able to edit its patterns. I know I can set it to use the `:CUSTOM-ID:` property instead of the normal cacophony of spontaneously generated ids, but what I would really like is to either remove this automatic id setting or to edit the pattern used by it, but I couldn't manage to find this information yet.

## edit:

I have found the [`ox-slimhtml`](http://bald.cat/slimhtml) package which greatly satisfies this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

http://bald.cat/slimhtml

I hope this can also be of use to others. It allows one to define classes and ids etc while still in the org buffer.

Comment: If this solved your question, you should accept the answer.